# Bitcoin Price Prediction using LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, bitcoin

So I wanted to predict the future price of bitcoin using LSTM but as I am new to this domain I'm stuck at what to do in order to print just the price of future lets say I want to predict the price for 3 months ahead from now what should i do in order to just get the closing price for BTC after 3 months from now?
It will be really appreciated if you guys can help me with this problem.

```
    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=test_size)
    X_train = extract_window_data(train_data, window_len, zero_base)
    X_test = extract_window_data(test_data, window_len, zero_base)
    y_train = train_data[target_col][window_len:].values
    y_test = test_data[target_col][window_len:].values
    if zero_base:
        y_train = y_train / train_data[target_col][:-window_len].values - 1
        y_test = y_test / test_data[target_col][:-window_len].values - 1

    return train_data, test_data, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

def build_lstm_model(input_data, output_size, neurons=100, activ_func='linear',
                     dropout=0.2, loss='mse', optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(input_data.shape[1], input_data.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=output_size))
    model.add(Activation(activ_func))

    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

np.random.seed(42)
window_len = 5
test_size = 0.2
zero_base = True
lstm_neurons = 100
epochs = 200
batch_size = 32
loss = 'mse'
dropout = 0.2
optimizer = 'adam'

train, test, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = prepare_data(
    hist, target_col, window_len=window_len, zero_base=zero_base, test_size=test_size)
print(X_test)

model = build_lstm_model(
    X_train, output_size=1, neurons=lstm_neurons, dropout=dropout, loss=loss,
    optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
preds = test[target_col].values[:-window_len] * (preds + 1)
preds = pd.Series(index=targets.index, data=preds)
print(test)
line_plot(targets, preds, 'actual', 'prediction', lw=3)
```

Comment: @suchislife can you further elaborate how to do it as I don't quietly understand what you said.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @suchislife, your comments are opinion based, and off-topic. OPs question is code related and on-topic. Instead of focusing on the `bitcoin` part of the question, do focus on the general question they are asking - `how to predict a value for a time series signal, n timestamps ahead`. That is a valid question, as many people use RNN/LSTM models stock and bitcoin predictions.

Comment: @SaadSajjad - your question is incomplete. Its unclear where you are facing issue in the lstm predictions. You have to be more specific on which part of code is failing and make the question more focused.

Comment: @Saad Sajjad Hope you got the link for trading view. 90%+ of the stuff you post here will not be answered. Good luck!